# Color Management "Look" setting VS controlling via environment

Tags: cycles-render-engine, filmic-blender

Just wanted to know if the contrast options in the "look" dropdown of Color Management settings do the same thing as just manipulating the environment, lights, materials, etc. basically, is the same result achievable using either method?

For instance, could you get deeper blues, or more saturated yellows using the Look settings vs just adjusting materials/environment lights/etc?

Any info is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can control contrast to a degree by how you set up lighting and film exposure, so most of the contrast options can be simulated by carefully doing those things.  The difference is that the contrast "look" can be changed without changing those things, so you can quickly switch between the two.

The trade-off is that the look applies globally, while lighting changes can adjust some areas of a scene without affecting others.